Drazin Inverse for special 2x2 Block Matrix
Introduction
The Drazin inverse $M^D$ of a matrix $M$ is defined by the relations
$$M^D M M^D = M^D,\quad M^D M = M M^D,\quad M^{k+1}M^D=M^k,$$
where the so-called index of the matrix $k=\text{Ind}(M)\in \mathbb{N}_0$ is defined as the smallest integer such that $\text{rank}(A^{k+1}) = \text{rank}(A^k)$.
If $k=1$, the Drazin inverse is identical to the group inverse, and the additional property $M M^D M=M$ holds. If $k=0$, we have $M^D=M^{-1}$.
Problem
I want to find the Drazin inverse of the following $2\times2$ block matrix:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&0\end{pmatrix},$$
with the diagonal blocks $A$ and $D=0$ being square matrices (for simplicity, all blocks are of equal dimensions).
As long as $A$ and the Schur complement $S=D-CA^{-1}B=-CA^{-1}B$ are invertible, this matrix can be easily inverted (see e.g. Wikipedia).
Now, in my case none of the submatrices $A,B$ or $C$ must have an inverse (in particular, but probably not so relevant: one or multiple columns of $M$ can be 0). We can assume that $\text{Ind}(M)\le 1$ (also for $A,B,C$).
The general problem of a Drazin inverse of a $2\times2$ block matrix (with $D\neq 0$) is an unsolved problem, so the literature provides only Drazin inverses for special cases.
However, all the cases I found were only concerned with Drazin inverses where (effectively) the offdiagonal blocks are 0, or where $A$ is invertible (often denoted as $A^\pi=I-A A^D=0$). I did not find any case where a diagonal block is 0.
The only somewhat applicable paper I found was (Castro-Gonzalez et al. 2010, Thrm 2.8), but they again demand conditions that boil down to $A^\pi=0$.
Is the problem with $D=0$ too hard to solve (or trivial?)? Or is it for some reason not of interest to study? Does anyone of you know a paper which deals with this case?
